# FullCalendar: coloring events from google calendar

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm trying to color specific events that are populated using the built-in googleCalendar plugin.

I've tried to color the events in Google Calendar, but the plugin ignores these. I've tried several of the examples from similar questions (mainly using 'eventRender:') but most of them are for a much older version of FullCalendar.  I've been poking and prodding eventRender to no avail.

I've gotten here:

```
eventRender: function( event ) { 
    if (event.event._def.title == "title of event") {
        let echild = event.el.querySelector('.fc-event-dot');
    }
},
```

This gets me the exact element I need to apply a color to in list mode.  If I do anything to the event object I get a JSON parse error.

Can anyone help?  I'd like to have the dayGrid item box and the list mode dot be specific colors to certain events titles.

Comment: Ok so now you need to set a colour for that element by changing its style property. That's pretty standard JavaScript, you should be able to google it.

Comment: Or if you want to achieve this in a more fullCalendar-y way, without messing with HTML elements, you could use the [eventDataTransform](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDataTransform) callback to check the event's title and then [set](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Event-setProp) one of the various [recognised colour properties](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) on the event and return it back to fullCalendar for rendering

Comment: I gave up and wrote my own calendar implementation from scratch.  The googleCalendar plugin was to blame for my difficulty, it is garbage.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested with eventDataTransform? That should work based on purely the title (as you mentioned) and has nothing whatsoever to do with the google plugin. That plugin just automates downloading of the events from google and transforming the data into fullCalendar's format, and then it goes through fullCalendar's loading process just like any other event from any other source. What _specifically_ was the issue you had with the plugin in your situation?